# Run function until another finishes Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to execute a function itself an amount n of times, this function is responsible for displaying a Dialog, but currently that amount of Dialog is generated simultaneously, I want that Dialog to be displayed and once it closes open the next one again, not all in one fell swoop.

Any advice for this?

This is my main code for this function

```
private fun onReportNotification(){
    showMessageDialog(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_REPORT_CREATED, getString(R.string.service_line_popup_push_title), getString(R.string.service_line_popup_push_body), getString(R.string.login_password_btn2),"")
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    checkForPendingTicketsToEvaluate()
}

private fun checkForPendingTicketsToEvaluate(){
    ServiceLineRepository.getAllReportsNotAualfied(applicationContext, serverClient){
        boolean: Boolean, unQualifiedReports: ArrayList<Entity.ServiceRequestedElement> ->
        if(boolean){
            unQualifiedReports.forEach {
                async {
                    currentId = it.id
                    currentService = it.requestedService
                    onReportNotification()
                }
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet for showMessageDialog()

```
open fun showMessageDialog(
    dialogType: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    acceptBtn: String,
    cancelBtn: String
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "showErrorDialog started, body=$body")
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val prev = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ConfirmDialog)
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev)
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    val arg = Bundle()
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TYPE_KEY, dialogType)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_BODY_KEY, body)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_TITLE_KEY, title)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_ACEEPT_BTN, acceptBtn)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_CANCEL_BTN, cancelBtn)
    val newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(arg)
    try {
        ft.let { newFragment.show(it, ConfirmDialog) }
        Log.d(TAG, "showMessageDialog, showing dialog")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        e.message?.let {
            Log.e(TAG, it)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: so you are going to loop `onReportNotification` as many as `unQualifiedReports`?

Comment: Yes, but I want to finish the current unQualifiedReport to start with the next one, but I can't, all reports are showing at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I can think of, probably not the best practice. But I think it would solve your problem.

First, pass your array size to `onReportNotification()` function and move it out from the loop, like this

```
        if(boolean){
            unQualifiedReports.forEach {
                async {
                    currentId = it.id
                    currentService = it.requestedService
                }
            }
            onReportNotification(unQualifiedReports.size)
        } else {

        }
```

Then, add array size argument in `onReportNotification()` function also pass it to `showMessageDialog()` method

```
private fun onReportNotification(totalDialogToBeShown: Int){
    showMessageDialog(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_REPORT_CREATED, getString(R.string.service_line_popup_push_title), getString(R.string.service_line_popup_push_body), getString(R.string.login_password_btn2),"", totalDialogToBeShown)
}
```

Lastly, in your `showMessageDialog()` function, change it to this

```
open fun showMessageDialog(
    dialogType: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    acceptBtn: String,
    cancelBtn: String,
    totalDialogToBeShown: Int
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "showErrorDialog started, body=$body")
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val prev = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ConfirmDialog)
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev)
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    val arg = Bundle()
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TYPE_KEY, dialogType)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_BODY_KEY, body)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_TITLE_KEY, title)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_ACEEPT_BTN, acceptBtn)
    arg.putString(ConfirmationDialog.DIALOG_TEXT_CANCEL_BTN, cancelBtn)
    val newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(arg)
    var numberOfShownDialog = 1
    newFragment.onDismiss(object : DialogInterface {
            override fun dismiss() {
                if (numberOfShownDialog < totalDialogToBeShown) {
                    numberOfShownDialog++
                    ft.let { newFragment.show(it, ConfirmDialog) }
                }
            }

            override fun cancel() {}
    })

    try {
        ft.let { newFragment.show(it, ConfirmDialog) }
        Log.d(TAG, "showMessageDialog, showing dialog")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        e.message?.let {
            Log.e(TAG, it)
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take note about the code, this will be so helpfiul, friend.

Comment: could you please leave an upvote & check if this truly helps?